# Cal symfony console task and do not wait

Tags: php, symfony, console

I want to call some console tasks written in `Symfony\Console` from the web that don't wait for a result, something like `exec php task.php > /dev/null &`.

Is there any utility for doing this in Symfony Console?

Comment: The example on the symfony2 website is really useful, http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html. But it will require executing from the command line not the web browser.

Comment: I have script for cron and I want to add button in administration to start that.

Comment: You can look into the Process component and have a controller use that to call your command process.